# Как работает интернет и dns в частности

Tags: сеть, dns, домен, wan

Как работает интернет? Знаю, что есть система dns, которая переводит введенное имя в ip-адрес. Но что фактически будет происходить, когда ввожу в браузере, например mail.ru?

1. Сначала проверяется кеш интернет-провайдера, правильно? Если кто-то
   когда-то вводил mail.ru, то будет сразу отправлен запрос по ip адресу
   mail.ru, который есть в кеше. И, кстати, какое оборудование
   интернет-провайдера принимает и отправляет запросы от компьютера
   пользователя (меня)?
2. А если в кеше интернет-провайдера нет информации о сайте, то
   провайдер отправляет запрос к корневому серверу, верно? Далее dns
   корневых серверов (один из 13-ти корневых серверов, точнее 13-ти
   ip-адресов) отправляет обратно ответ с ip адресом доменной зоны ru на
   мой компьютер, верно? И мой компьютер отправляет снова запрос на этот ip
   адрес dns доменной зоны ru, верно? Но не пойму где находятся dns
   доменной зоны ru? Это набор независимых серверов, которые находятся у
   регистраторов хостинга или я что-то неправильно понимаю? Т.е. где находятся и кому принадлежат dns сервера корневой зоны понятно, а где находятся и кому принадлежат dns сервера, например зоны ru? или любой другой второго уровня?.

Comment: я бы порекомендовал начинать с прочтения [википедийной статьи](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNS).

Comment: читал, там не написано про связь маршрутизации начального запроса от провайдера и далее до доменной зоны первого уровня.

Answer (score 2):

предуведомление: изложенное ниже является очень упрощённой «картиной мира», не претендует на полноту и филигранную точность.

### по поводу работы вашего бразуера

dns-серверы общего пользования (работающие у вашего интернет-провайдера, у крупных провайдеров сетевых услуг — например, [google](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Public_DNS) или [yandex](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AF%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81.DNS)), как правило, являются *рекурсивными*.

т.е., на запрос от вашего браузера (точнее, от кода внутри вашей операционной системы) с просьбой предоставить [a-записи](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%8B_%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B9_DNS) (их, частенько, бывает несколько больше одной) для доменного имени *mail.ru*, они вернут именно *a-записи*, скрыв от кода вашей операционной системы (и, соответственно, от вашего браузера) все ненужные подробности.

собственно, насколько мне известно, ни ваш браузер, ни тот самый код в операционной системе, просто не «обучены» пользоваться системой dns как таковой. это им совершенно не требуется — такими вещами занимаются те самые специализированные программы, называемые dns-серверами.

---

### по поводу работы dns-серверов

обычное состояние dns-сервера при поступлении запроса от клиента — это поиск информации в кэше. поработав всего несколько часов, более или менее нагруженный сервер уже запасётся ответами «на любой вкус и цвет», благо подавляющее большинство запросов муссирует относительно небольшой массив информации.

но, допустим, сервер только что перезапустили «на холодную», т.е., с полной очисткой кэша.

и вот приходит к нему запрос на *a-записи* для доменного имени `mail.ru.`. да-да, полное доменное имя включает и точку в конце — это начало иерархии, «корень» (помните про «корневые серверы»?), это как `/` в файловой системе unix-подобных операционных систем или как «мой компьютер» (или что-то в этом духе) в ms/windows-подобных операционных системах. впрочем, ввиду сложившейся традиции, нынче nameserver-ы поймут вас и без «корневой» точки. более того, в некоторых современных клиентских программах (браузерах, почтовых клиентах и т.п.) указание этой точки может быть воспринято как ошибка! (куда катится этот мир?)

список «[корневых серверов](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8B_DNS)» либо прямо «зашит» в коде dns-сервера, либо записан в его конфигурационных файлах (либо и то и другое вместе), поэтому первое, что сделает наш dns-сервер — выберет из этого списка какой-нибудь ip-адрес и пошлёт запрос вида «сообщите nameserver-ы, обслуживающие зону `ru.`» (примеры я буду приводить для программы `dig`):

```
$ dig @199.7.83.42 ns ru.
;ru.                IN  NS
ru.         172800  IN  NS  a.dns.ripn.net.
ru.         172800  IN  NS  b.dns.ripn.net.
ru.         172800  IN  NS  d.dns.ripn.net.
ru.         172800  IN  NS  e.dns.ripn.net.
ru.         172800  IN  NS  f.dns.ripn.net.
a.dns.ripn.net.     172800  IN  A   193.232.128.6
b.dns.ripn.net.     172800  IN  A   194.85.252.62
d.dns.ripn.net.     172800  IN  A   194.190.124.17
e.dns.ripn.net.     172800  IN  A   193.232.142.17
f.dns.ripn.net.     172800  IN  A   193.232.156.17
a.dns.ripn.net.     172800  IN  AAAA    2001:678:17:0:193:232:128:6
b.dns.ripn.net.     172800  IN  AAAA    2001:678:16:0:194:85:252:62
d.dns.ripn.net.     172800  IN  AAAA    2001:678:18:0:194:190:124:17
e.dns.ripn.net.     172800  IN  AAAA    2001:678:15:0:193:232:142:17
f.dns.ripn.net.     172800  IN  AAAA    2001:678:14:0:193:232:156:17
```

вот сервер уже и получил первые пять записей для кэша (если быть совсем точным, то пятнадцать, но это сейчас несущественно). теперь, при поступлении другого запроса по поводу домена в зоне `ru.` он уже не будет обращаться к корневым серверам, а обратится к одному из пяти только что полученных серверов.

следующий запрос «сообщите nameserver-ы, обслуживающие зону `mail.ru.`» уйдёт к случайно выбранному серверу из этого списка:

```
$ dig @193.232.128.6 ns mail.ru.
;mail.ru.           IN  NS
MAIL.RU.        345600  IN  NS  ns2.mail.RU.
MAIL.RU.        345600  IN  NS  ns1.mail.RU.
ns1.MAIL.RU.        345600  IN  A   217.69.139.112
ns2.MAIL.RU.        345600  IN  A   94.100.180.138
```

вот в кэше уже есть информация и о зоне `mail.ru.` — теперь для запросов по поводу любых имён в этой зоне уже не потребуется обращаться ни к «корневым серверам», ни даже к серверам, обслуживающим зону `ru.`.

и, наконец, финальный запрос к случайно выбранному одному из двух серверов — «сообщите a-записи для серверов, откликающихся на имя `mail.ru.`»:

```
$ dig @217.69.139.112 a mail.ru.
;mail.ru.           IN  A
mail.ru.        60  IN  A   217.69.139.201
mail.ru.        60  IN  A   94.100.180.200
mail.ru.        60  IN  A   94.100.180.202
mail.ru.        60  IN  A   217.69.139.202
mail.ru.        600 IN  NS  ns2.mail.ru.
mail.ru.        600 IN  NS  ns1.mail.ru.
ns1.mail.ru.        600 IN  A   217.69.139.112
ns1.mail.ru.        600 IN  AAAA    2a00:1148:db00::2
ns2.mail.ru.        600 IN  A   94.100.180.138
ns2.mail.ru.        600 IN  AAAA    2a00:1148:db00::1
```

получено в ответ четыре *a-записи*. все они и будут отправлены в ответ клиенту (и, конечно, будут закэшированы для последующего использования).

Comment: _и, конечно, будут закэшированы для последующего использования_ Да, конечно будут, только вот у конкретно `mail.ru` выбранного для примера, будут закешированы не более, чем на 60 секунд (для A) :)

Comment: @Mike, во-первых, пример выбрал автор вопроса, во-вторых, небольшой ttl — это обычная история: `google.com soa ns2.google.com. dns-admin.google.com. 111759015 900 900 1800 60` (последнее число — [minimum ttl](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1035#section-3.3.13)).

Comment: Принцип работы примерно понятен. Я, видимо, не совсем понимаю, что такое dns физически. Т.е. сначала идет запрос именно к dns, да? А где находится dns? у провайдера или где? К кому сначала отправляется запрос?

Comment: @ПавелИгорев, браузер спрашивает у операционной системы. не «сначала», а вообще, целиком и полностью. а операционная система может переправить запрос dns-серверу, который указан в её настройках.

Comment: @ПавелИгорев, «dns физически» не существует. это domain name system, описанная в различных [rfc](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/RFC). ещё раз настоятельно рекомендую прочитать хотя бы википедийную статью про dns.

Comment: Почему dns не существуют физически? есть же корневые dns сервера, согласно википедии их более 200 по всему миру (13 ip адресов). только непонятно зачем так много, они ведь по идее только сообщают информацию о доменах верхнего уровня, а их не так много. Также взять, к примеру доменную зону ру  https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/.ru  - написано, что их обслуживает 8 серверов, тоже ведь физические?

Comment: *Почему dns не существуют физически?* — потому что невозможно ответить на вопрос «где находится система доменных имён физически?», как, например, невозможно ответить на вопрос «где находится банковская система физически?». ниформация, хранящаяся в корневых серверах, — это лишь мизерный кусочек информации, хранящейся в *распределённой базе данных dns*. но и распределённая база данных dns — это далеко не вся система доменных имён. потому что это, в первую очередь, протоколы, и, во вторую очередь, программы, реализующие взаимодействие между компьютерами согласно этим протоколам.