# Как перенести адрес сайта с одного сервера на другой?

Tags: dns

Есть старый сервер на виртуалке, и его надо перенести на новый выделенный сервер. Я могу установить всё что надо на сервере и создать конфиг для апача.

Где мне исправить доменные имена сайта и где они вообще находятся?

В resolv.conf есть что-то похожее. Но, если я правильно понимаю, то, скопировав там адрес ip, я должна перейти на один из сайтов, но это вообще какие-то нерабочие ip, которые никуда не ведут.

Заходила в /etc/apache2/sites-available - там есть общий конфиг (наверно, это потому что виртуалка) для всех сайтов, но без доменных имен.

Сервер - ubuntu.

Как это можно сделать? Или это что-то нереально сложное?

Comment: Если я вас правильно понял, то вам надо искать вообще не на машине. А начинать с регистратора доменных имен, у которого зарегестрирован ваш домен. В управлении доменом смотрите на какие адреса ведут "NS" записи. Если эти NS так же смотрят на вашего регистратора или еще куда нибудь, то идете в управление доменом там, куда смотрят "NS" и меняете там уже указатели имен на ip-адреса, т.е. "A"-записи

Comment: NS? - но это же ServerName в конфиге апача.

Comment: NS это не ServerName в конфиге. http://www.expertplus.ru/information/faq/chto-takoe-ns-servera/

Comment: Нет, в терминах DNS NS запись это запись указывающая имя сервера имен отвечающего на запросы по данному домену. Что вы попасть скажем на сайт google.ru ваша операционная система сначала должна определить IP-адрес веб-сервера куда слать запрос. Для этого она (в сильно упрощенном виде) лезет к регистраторам имен зоны "ru." и спрашивает "кто отвечает за адреса "google.ru.", NS сервер зоны "ru." отвечает: "за google.ru.отвечает ns1.google.ru. вот его IP", далее отправляется запрос на ns1.google.ru и он дает IP адрес веб сервера. Так что в любом случае ноги растут от регистратора доменного имени

Comment: но это прям надо искать в админке хостинга?

Comment: Даже не факт, что хостинга. Зависит от способа приобретения домена. Если у хостинга, то да, если нет, то скорее регистратора надо искать.

Comment: кошмар. спасибо за помощь.

Comment: @КаришА Если не помните кто регистратор, то зайдите скажем на https://www.nic.ru/whois/  (для доменов зоны ru) и впишите там имя своего домена, увидите NS записи и имя в поле `registrar:` могут подсказать кто регистратор домена

Comment: ок. спс. напиши, пжл, свой ответ, я его отмечу как решение.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

насколько я понял, вам надо изменить ip-адрес, в который [резолвится](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System#Address_resolution_mechanism) имя вашего домена. посмотреть текущий адрес можно с помощью, например, такой команды:

```
$ host имя.вашего.домена
```

браузеры по всему миру получают эту информацию от [системы доменных имён](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNS). первоисточником же информации о вашем домене являются *nameserver-ы*, обслуживающие ваш домен. узнать их имена несложно с помощью, например, такой команды:

```
$ host -t ns имя.вашего.домена
```

обращаться же с запросом по поводу смены ip-адреса вам надо к *регистратору* вашего домена. т.е., к тому, кому вы «платите за домен». обычно у регистраторов имеется web-интерфейс для изменения настроек домена, в том числе и ip-адреса. в таком случае и «запрос» не потребуется — достаточно залогиниться в этом интерфейсе и внести нужные изменения.

ещё довольно часто *хостеры*, т.е. те, кто предоставляет услуги по размещению реальных/виртуальных серверов, одновременно оказывают и услуги *регистратора* домена, и предоставляют единый web-интерфейс для управления как сервером, так и доменом.

---

дополнительная информация:

- [Как работает интернет и dns в частности](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/481006/178576)
- [Как работает система доменных имен](http://info.nic.ru/st/8/out_16.shtml)