# как находится сервер, на катором выложен сайт?

Tags: сервер, dns, ip-address, domain

1. когда в браузере мы пишем домен сайта (например, `www.google.com`), браузер отправляет это имя днс-серверу. там находится ip-адрес этого домена и отправлиаетса браузеру. браузер делает запрос на этот ip-адрес, и здесь возникает вопрос: как находится сервер, на котором расположен ip-адрес сайта?

   если этот вопрос неправильный, то следуший вопрос:
2. если этот ip-адрес и являетса ip-адресом сервера, то как находится нужный сайт в этом сервере, потому что в одном сервере может быть много сайтов?

Comment: 1. На всех маршрутизаторах есть таблицы маршрутизации, в которых написано, в какой конкретно сетевой порт нужно отправлять запрос для определённых диапазонов ip-адресов, и так постепенно через цепочку маршрутизаторов запрос приходит к нужному серверу

Comment: 2. Внутри запроса указывается домен, сервер может прочитать этот домен и выбрать нужный сайт

Comment: спасибо за ваш ответ. то есть доменный ip адресс(тот который дает DNS сервер), это не ip адресс сервера, а доменное имя с машиночитабелном варианте, который находятся в каком то определионном сервере??

Comment: ip адресс - это ip адресс. А уже вебсервер, запущенный на этом сервере (или даже серверах) по содержимому заголовков (где обычно бывает и host, который содержит доменное имя) уже определяет, как именно обработать запрос.

Comment: @SamvelGhumashyan нет, DNS-сервер даёт именно ip-адрес сервера и запрос отправляется по ip-адресу, а уже внутри запроса прописывается домен

Comment: спасибо болшое....

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/481006/178576

Comment: Вам скорей всего нужно ознакомиться и понять саму концепцию работы DNS сервера. Перечитайте статью "[Что такое DNS-сервер](https://seo-intro.com/chto-takoe-dns-server/)?", думаю тут и будут ответы на ваши вопросы

Answer (score 1):

> 1. как находится сервер, на котором расположен ip-адрес сайта?

[ip-пакет](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2_TCP/IP), отправленный с вашего компьютера по данному ip-адресу, за время движения пройдёт цепочку других компьютеров, так называемых [маршрутизаторов](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%88%D1%80%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80).

у каждого компьютера, взаимодействующего с другими компьютерами по сети, в том числе и у вашего компьютера, и у вышеупомянутых маршрутизаторов, имеется [таблица маршрутизации](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%88%D1%80%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F).

на основании этой таблицы (и ip-адреса конечного получателя пакета) компьютер и определяет, какому очередному маршрутизатору надо передать пакет.

> 2. как находится нужный сайт в этом сервере, потому что в одном сервере может быть много сайтов?

а ваш браузер сам указывает имя веб-сервера внутри [http-сообщения](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP#%D0%A1%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0_HTTP-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F).

в случае же обращения по протоколу https (т.е., с шифрованием трафика) браузер использует [sni](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication):

> Server Name Indication (SNI) — расширение компьютерного протокола TLS[1], которое позволяет клиентам сообщать имя хоста, с которым он желает соединиться во время процесса «рукопожатия».